# C# style properties in python

Tags: c#, python, properties, nested

I am looking for a way to define properties in Python similar to C#, with nested get/set definitions.
This is how far I got:

```
#### definition ####    

def Prop(fcn):
    f = fcn()
    return property(f['get'], f['set'])


#### test ####

class Example(object):

    @Prop
    def myattr():

        def get(self):
            return self._value

        def set(self, value):
            self._value = value

        return locals()  #  <- how to get rid of this?

e = Example()
e.myattr = 'somevalue' 
print e.myattr
```

The problem with this is, that it still needs the definition to 'return locals()'.
Is there a way to get rid of it?
Maybe with a nested decorator?

Comment: Maybe I don't get something, but why are classic `myattr = property(fget=get_value, fset=set_value)` not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `return get, set` (a much more elegant approach) and make your `Prop` into

```
def Prop(fcn):
    g, s = fcn()
    return property(g, s)
```

There is however no *clean* way to not require *any* `return` statement in the decorated function.  A function with internal `def` statements, just like one with internal assignments, does not actually *execute* those statements until it gets called -- the objects and names said assignments and `def`s are supposed to build and bind are, literally, nowhere to be found.

Once it *is* called, said names and objects are local to the function -- so, they go away unless external references to them exist... and there's really no more elegant way to ensure such external references to local names exist, besides `return`ing them in some form.

The problem comes from insisting that you want to decorate a *function* object (which keeps its local names very much to itself, by design).  Everything would be fine and dandy if you agreed to use the correct keyword instead of `def` for the decorated thingy -- that correct keyword is `class`.  (Note, you need Python 2.6 or better for this purpose)...:

```
def Prop(cls):
    f = cls.__dict__
    return property(f['get'], f['set'])


#### test ####

class Example(object):

    @Prop
    class myattr():

        def get(self):
            print 'getting', self._value
            return self._value

        def set(self, value):
            print 'setting', value
            self._value = value


e = Example()
e.myattr = 'somevalue' 
print e.myattr
```

Classes are much less secretive than functions wrt what's "inside" them, so a *class* decorator can easily accomplish what you're after.  Note the tiny changes: `__dict__` to access the dict of the class being decorated, `s/def/class/` in the object being decorated, and removal of the `return` statement you dislike.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate explanation. The class decorator removes the 'return locals()' but adds an inner class which 'feels wrong' to me, too. (The whole thing being just a matter of taste regarding syntax). There is no way to somehow tack the 'return locals()' afterwards using reflection?

Comment: @3D-Grabber, the "inner class" disappears because the decorator just uses it and doesn't return it.  Yes, you **can** get crazy with byte-code disassembly and introspection to make the **wrong** keyword (`def`) behave _almost_ as well as the **right** keyword in this context (`class`) naturally, seamlessly, and effortlessly would -- but, having done my share of bytecode hacks and then some, I now refuse to be an enabler in such a self-destructive endeavor;-).  50+ lines of intricate, fragile, delicate code to let you say `def` when you **really** mean `class` but "dislike it"?!  Just say NO!-)